# Do Egyptian mummies contain DNA? If so, was it viable enough to analyzed it?

Tags: ancient-egypt, egypt

I just had my DNA completed with 23andme and was wondering if we have any information regarding the ancestry of Epyptian mummies.

Comment: I've wondered about this myself. DNA starts to get broken down as soon as the containing life form dies, so how there is any left after 3000 years I do not understand. I would not be surprised if the analyses are not accurate.

Comment: Agreed, the process I did with 23andme (spitting into a container) has to be completely different from the process of extracting DNA from these!

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_DNA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, [Wikipedia does have a page for it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNA-tested_mummies), so yes it has been done.

For example, Ramses III had the [E-V38](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplogroup_E-V38) Y Chromosome Haplogroup. Interestingly, most of the modern people who have a large preponderance of this pattern are West African. However, some of it is found all over Africa, and even in about 10% of modern Eqyptians. So I don't think a lot can really be read into it (other than that his recent lineage probably hailed from Africa somewhere).

Comment: thanks, i searched but for some reason didnt see the wiki! I'm new here, when I get enough rep i'll upvote :)